# Jackson ObjectMapper different behavior on Windows and MacOS

Tags: windows, macos, maven, spring-boot, jackson

I have implemented the following test in my Spring Boot 2/Maven project:

```
@Autowired
private com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Test
public void testJSON() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    String json = "{\"additionalDecisionGroupId\":null,\"decisionNameFilterPattern\":null,\"filterQueries\":[{\"type\":\"RangeQuery\",\"characteristicId\":2,\"value\":null,\"optionHolder\":{\"optionId\":1,\"propertyHolders\":[{\"propertyId\":4,\"value\":[1,5]}],\"propertyOperator\":\"AND\"}}],\"sortCriteriaIds\":null,\"sortWeightCriteriaDirection\":null,\"sortTotalVotesCriteriaDirection\":null,\"sortCriteriaCoefficients\":null,\"sortCharacteristicId\":null,\"sortCharacteristicDirection\":null,\"sortDecisionPropertyName\":\"createDate\",\"sortDecisionPropertyDirection\":\"ASC\",\"excludeChildDecisionIds\":null,\"includeChildDecisionIds\":null,\"excludeCharacteristicIds\":null,\"includeCharacteristicIds\":null,\"includeChildDecisionOwnedByUserIds\":null,\"pageNumber\":0,\"pageSize\":100,\"persistent\":null,\"iso6391\":null}";

    DecisionAnalysisRequest request = objectMapper.readValue(json, DecisionAnalysisRequest.class);

    RangeQuery rangeQuery = (RangeQuery) request.getFilterQueries().iterator().next();

    assertNotNull(rangeQuery);
    assertNotNull(rangeQuery.getOptionHolder());
}
```

Under the Windows 10 the test sometimes works but most of the time fails because of `optionHolder = null`. Under the MacOS on the same sources the test works properly.

What can be the reason of such behavior and how to fix it ?

**UPDATED**

It was my fault:

```
@JsonCreator
public RangeQuery(@JsonProperty("characteristicId") Long characteristicId, @JsonProperty("optionHolders") OptionHolder optionHolder, @JsonProperty("value") Object value) {
    super(characteristicId, value, StringUtils.EMPTY, optionHolder);
}
```

I incorrectly named the `JsonProperty` as `optionHolders` instead of correct `optionHolder`.

But why does it work on the MacOS is still the open question..

Comment: You can configure the `ObjectMapper` to include null values ... `objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);` this might help avoid any platform specific behaviours.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have already added `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL` into my `application.properties` It doesn't help.