# POST to Spring/Hibernate backend with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm trying to send this JSON to my Java backend

```
{  
 "title": "TITOLO", 
 "description": "DESCRIZIONE", 
 "mediaType": "MEDIATYPE" 
}
```

but for some reasons, I cannot write it correctly to my DB. Some teammates can do it without problems but I get this error from Postman:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1526753419760,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class isssr.ticketsystem.entity.Ticket]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `isssr.ticketsystem.entity.Ticket` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 2]",
    "path": "/ticketsystem/ticket"
}
```

I wrote on their local DB without problems but they cannot do the same to mine.

Why this?

My OS is MacOS X High Sierra 10.13.4, using as IDE Intellij IDEA.

**UPDATE**

Problem was Java 10.
With a downgrade to Java 8, all works fine.

Comment: What class does this json payload is supposed to map to?

Comment: Does the ticket pojo have empty constructor? Or are you maybe using some annotation that creates default constructor?

Comment: @vanillaSugar actually there is a constructor, that is not empty, and my team mates can create a row without any problems

Comment: I understand. If you can, try to add an empty constructor and see if it helps. Things can be tricky even if that seems impossible

Comment: @vanillaSugar I tried but It creates a row in the DB with all columns as null

Comment: Ok, revert that change then. Try to add annotation @JsonProperty to every field in Ticket. i.e:  @JsonProperty("Name")
                                       public String name;

Comment: @vanillaSugar yeah, but why my team mates can do it without problems?

Comment: Maybe they have different jackson version than you

Comment: How can we check? @vanillaSugar

Comment: Find jackson in your dependencies and check its version. i.e. if you have pom.xml you can find it there

Comment: @vanillaSugar we checked and got the same.

Comment: Do you have exactly the same project? Is it on the version control?

Comment: @vanillaSugar yes, imported from GitHub.

Comment: I suspect that jackson can behave differently on different OS. In this question we can see different behaviour as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901381/jackson-objectmapper-different-behavior-on-windows-and-macos     .. I couldn't find the reason for this, but if you annotate pojos with JsonProperty it works right?

Comment: Where should i put it? @vanillaSugar

Comment: Loog at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583638/when-is-the-jsonproperty-property-used-and-what-is-it-used-for  ..also you can look here http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: that's not an explenation refer to my team mates correctly doing the save on the DB. @vanillaSugar

Comment: Problem was java 10.
Downgraded to 8 and all works fine. @vanillaSugar

Comment: @JackLametta I see. But it is not very good solution to downgrade java

Comment: @vanillaSugar actually it is not, but it would have required to anyone in the team to upgrade to my java.

Comment: @JackLametta I thought that everyone had java 10. Alright, then good for you